# How to execute Javascript in dynamically loaded HTML

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, dynamic

I have a webpage in which I dynamically change the HTML in the `contentEditor` div, depending on what topic the user picks in the navigation menu. The HTML in this `contentEditor` div gets loaded from external scripts:

```
function updateContentEditor() {
var window = document.getElementById('contentEditor');

if(editingPage == "Homepagina") {       
    $("#contentEditor").load("http://www.imaginedigital.nl/CMS/Editor/Homepage9.html");
new jscolor.color($line.find('input[name=color]')[0], {});
}
/* and so on... */
}
```

Now this works perfectly fine, the correct html gets loaded for every page. I do have a problem with Javascript though..

One of the textfields in the script that I have should be a color picker:
[image]
The color picker works perfectly when I load the page itself in my browser, but when I load this page in my `contentEditor` div, it does not get loaded:

[image]

The color picker is an external Javascript (downloaded from: http://jscolor.com/download.php).

I already tried loading it in both the main page as the editor page (editor is the one I load inside the main page), but that won't solve the problem either.

**Question**
How do I make sure my Javascript gets executed when I load a page containing that script inside another HTML page's div?

**PLEASE NOTE**
I do have other javascript in the editor that I load inside my main page. that is javascript that shows a pop up div. that works without any problem.

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/538745/how-to-tell-if-a-script-tag-failed-to-load) what you're looking for?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, But I am afraid this is not what I'm looking for. When I load the page itself in my browser, it works perfectly fine. The problem only occurs when I load the page inside another page. Any ideas on how I solve that problem?

Comment: just recall your color picker function on the reloaded html to reassign the picker like ``onAjaxLoaded(function(data){ setcontent(data); colorpicker(); })`` - edit ok the problem with your lib is that you only can reassign the whole html document with the colorpicker - everytime your ajax is loaded you setup a colorpicker maybee on elements that have allready modif.

Comment: I am not familiar with Ajax and I am not using it, so I don't think that will be the problem. Thanks for the suggestion though!

Comment: @Imaginedigital so, you're saying, when you load the url, there's nothing? Try doing that, use google chrome and check the console for any error.

Comment: @sulavvr, that is true! when I load the URL in any browser, nothing is wrong. I may be a little further though: I added an unload="alert('loaded')" function on the script. Now, When I load the URL in a browser, it shows an alert confirming that the script is loaded. When I load the page in my other page, i don't het this alert, so basically it does not get loaded. Any idea how i solve this?

Comment: Ok, does your chrome console show any error? Maybe something like "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present...".

Comment: nothing, neither does safari console. Probably because it does not even try to load it? is there any function that I can trigger to load it, as it apparently does not work the automatic way?

Comment: Ok, then what is the URL of the page you are trying to load it on?

Comment: http://www.imaginedigital.nl/CMS/Main.php

Comment: and just in case: The url of the page i am loading in that page is imagine digital.nl/CMS/Editor/Homepage1.html

Comment: Ok, did you try doing this, using relative path instead of absolute path.`$("#contentEditor").load("Editor/Homepage9.html");`

Comment: I just did it but nothing changes. It is very strange, as the other JS I have just works (the popups from the blue buttons). I load the scripts the exact same way...

Comment: Can you try something like this, in your JS file, `$(document).ready(function()){ $('.button').on('click', '#contentEditorDiv', function(){ //call the color popup } }`, instead of doing the `onclick = popup()`..

Comment: the on `click = popup()`; is not the function that calls the color picker. the color picker should be called by the `<input id="background" class="color"` the class=color should do the trick, and normally does

Comment: Hmmmm.. ok, what happens if you do something like this, `$('id').load('url', function(){ $('#background').addClass('color') })`.. adding class after the load.

Comment: ok, I think this might help,  reinitialize the jscolor.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8366454/newly-added-elements-using-delegate-wont-bind-jscolor-js ... :D hopefully!

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I added the re-initialization from the answer you posted after the new html gets loaded (see updated question), but it does not help, neither does the line of code you posted. Should I implement them on a certain line?

Comment: @Imaginedigital First of all, the $line is undefined, so you can't use it, second of all you can't use `input[name=color]` because your element doesn't have a name attribute with the value 'color'. So, maybe try this.. `new jscolor.init();`, and try this on the load callback function.. which would look like this.. `$('#content....').load('path', function() { new jscolor.init(); });`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `window.onload=function(){SomeJavaScriptCode};` in the script you are loading?.

Take a look at this, the `beforeload` is what you might be looking for:

[How do you detect that a script was loaded *and* executed in a chrome extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18323757/how-do-you-detect-that-a-script-was-loaded-and-executed-in-a-chrome-extension)

Comment: I know it does not get loaded due to the fact that I added an unload "alert('loaded')", which does not show up when I load the page inside my other page. How do I make sure it actually gets loaded?

Comment: Have you tried using a callback function after loading?

`if(editingPage == "Homepagina") {       
    $("#contentEditor").load("http://www.imaginedigital.nl/CMS/Editor/Homepage9.html", function(response, status, xhr){
  if ( status == "success" ) {
   new jscolor.color($line.find('input[name=color]')[0], {});
  }
 });`

Answer (score 0):

you say that it dont load in the contenteditor id ?
Please check first -> Are you using jQuery or Pure JS

```
function updateContentEditor() {
var window = document.getElementById('contentEditor');

if(editingPage == "Homepagina") {       
    $("#contentEditor").load("http://www.imaginedigital.nl/CMS/Editor/Homepage9.html");
}
/* and so on... */
}
```

From your code you are mixing Pure JS and jQuery + dont know are you using jQuery or not

```
document.getElementById('contentEditor'); -> Pure JS
$("#contentEditor").load("http://www.imaginedigital.nl/CMS/Editor/Homepage9.html"); -> jQuery
```

If you are not using jQuery -> `$("#contentEditor").load("http://www.imaginedigital.nl/CMS/Editor/Homepage9.html"); -> jQuery`
will not work

Comment: I am using JQuery. The page itself gets loaded perfectly, the only problem is that the javascript is not working. any idea how I can solve that? please let me know if you need more information for that

Comment: So the script you first run (success one) is inside Homepage9.html ?And then you load it to #contentEditor which load the Homepage9.html with all its script ? I suggest you cut the script from Homepage9.html to your main site which load Homepage9.html

Comment: I tried that and it is obviously not working as quotation marks cross each other interrupting the script.